# Unterminated conditional directive in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, preprocessor-directive

What's wrong here:

```
#define CONTROLS_OFFSET 100
#ifdef  CONTROLS_OFFSET//Unterminated conditional directive it says
#define FIND_MAIN_MENU 3
```

Why do i get this error?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

An `#ifdef`, like an `#if`, needs to be balanced by an `#endif`. In this case, that would probably go immediately after your `#define` line.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  NSLog (@"This is a test");
#endif
```